# How to instantiate manually the method newJob of quartz jobDetail?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I worked on a Project and I have a problem. The newJob method that automatically instantiates my type of object jobdetail can't benefit me. I need to manually instantiate the newJob to pass it as a parameter by the object of my choice, but I don't know how. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly pass a parameter to a job.
What you can do, instead, is use `JobDataMap` which will be passed directly by the scheduler as explained [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.html). For example (in Java):

```
// define the job and tie it to our DumbJob class
JobDetail job = newJob(DumbJob.class)
  .withIdentity("myJob", "group1") // name "myJob", group "group1"
  .usingJobData("jobSays", "Hello World!")
  .usingJobData("myFloatValue", 3.141f)
  .build();
```

And, in the job, you can access the map like this:

```
public class DumbJob implements Job {

    public DumbJob() {
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
      throws JobExecutionException
    {
      JobKey key = context.getJobDetail().getKey();

      JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

      String jobSays = dataMap.getString("jobSays");
      float myFloatValue = dataMap.getFloat("myFloatValue");

      System.err.println("Instance " + key + " of DumbJob says: " + jobSays + ", and val is: " + myFloatValue);
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: So i see your point of view but i want to redefine the method newJob of quartz jobdetail. It's possible?

Comment: Well, that's the way the system works. If you want to change this I think you need to start from the source code. Obviously it's possibile, but maybe it's a little bit too expensive, no?

Comment: Yes...this way will be too large.